# Vertx Verticle gets undeployed if uncaught exception happens

Tags: vert.x, vertx-httpclient

I am deploying a TrendsVerticle "com.example.test.trends" and calling this from MainVerticle.
Issue happens when some uncaught exception happens in TrendsVerticle, the next time when I call the API I get this error and my whole verticle gets un deployed.

```
{
 "status": "FAILURE",
 "reason": "(NO_HANDLERS,-1) No handlers for address com.example.test.trends"
}
```

Why this behavior? shouldn't Vertx just handle this and not remove my verticle.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983904/verticles-and-uncaught-exceptions this does not have answers what I'm looking for

Comment: Please post your code, as this shouldn't happen. Even if your verticle throws Throwable, it still won't be undeployed by itself.